# How to monitor absolute usage of cpu and memory within a time period in Azure Data Explorer per user/pricipal?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, adx

The insights and metrics are not satisfactory, so I am looking for a way where I can see the absolute CPU and memory usage within a time period per user/principal. Is there a Kusto command or any other solutions?

- .show queries
- Docs
- Insights
- Metrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

monitoring resource utilization per principal identity over time can be achieved using [`.show commands-and-queries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/commands-and-queries) or [commands and queries diagnostics logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/using-diagnostic-logs?tabs=commands-and-queries)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know which unit the TotalCpu and MemoryPeak in result of ".show commands-and-queries" have? TotalCpu is a timespan? I want to get: "This principal used x% of the available CPU power". And MemoryPeak is in Byte, right?

Comment: Total CPU is a timespan, and Memory Peak is in bytes. In order to calculate the percentage of all available CPU you'll need to know the amount of nodes and cores in the cluster. But I personally wouldn't recommend that (as the cluster can automatically scale out/in). Instead, you could sum the total cpu for all users, then divide the consumption of each user by that to get an estimate of the percentage.

Comment: Thank you. What exactly is a timespan in terms of cpu? And is the sum of the total cpu (in timespan) per user the total available cpu power within the cluster?

Comment: You can read more about CPU time here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time